# System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime, objectdatasource

I am using c#.net. Thanks in advance for any help.

I am using a Repeater and a ObjectDataSource. I use LINQ to connect to the database. This requires a parameter to be passed through (used within the WHERE clause)

```
    public IQueryable<comments> GetComments(DateTime todaysDate)
    {
        return (from c in dc.comments
                where displayDate.Date == todayDate.Date
                select c);
    }
```

I am encounting the error above and don't know why. Here is where the problem lies:

```
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="<%=Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now)%>" Name="todayDate" Type="DateTime" />
```

If I provide a actual date it works. For example:

```
<asp:Parameter DefaultValue="02/09/2009" Name="todayDate" Type="DateTime" />
```

I have also tried the following and recieved the same error:

```
DateTime.Now.Date
Datetime.Now
Datetime.Today
Datetime.Now.ToString
Datetime.Now.Date.ToString.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Clare

Comment: DateTime.Now is a DateTime object, you don't need to Convert it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for you help. You put me on the right track.

After finding out I could set the DefaultValue within the code behind I have another look around the web and found [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/Learn/Data-Access/tutorial-06-cs.aspx).

This is now working.

Here is my code:

```
    protected void comments_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.InputParameters["todayDate"] = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

However please note first you must create a 'Selecting' event (within the properties tab).

I hope this is the correct way of doing it. Does anyone have any comments on this?

Thanks again

Clare

Answer (score 2):

Using <%= .. %> syntax in a server control () is not possible. Use code-behind to set the property.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the SelectParameter in the page load.  Just add this -

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["todayDate"].DefaultValue = Datetime.Now;
```

Edit:  Thanks Hans for the correction.

Comment: I have added that into my page load but i am getting the following error message - System.Web.UI.WebControls.ObjectDataSource.SelectParameters' cannot be used like a method

Comment: in C#, use SelectParameters["todayDate"], that is [] instead of ().

Comment: I now get the following error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Even if I put a 'if' statement round it (checking if not null) it still gives the same error.

Comment: Did you replace SqlDataSource1 with the name of your SqlDataSource object? Also make sure you have this line of code in your HTML- <asp:Parameter Name="todayDate" Type="DateTime" />.  Also you can try to use this line in the code behind instead - SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@todayDate", Datetime.Now);.

Answer (score 0):

If you've copied and pasted your code, then you might have a typo in the function - the function parameter is named today**s**Date, but the where statement uses todayDate (which is your ASP parameter).

If this is not the case, please post where you call your GetComments function from.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo on my part. Within my code it is todayDate

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is the correct location of the error?  Here is what Convert.ToDateTime does:

```
    public static DateTime ToDateTime(bool value)
    {
        return ((IConvertible) value).ToDateTime(null);
    }
```

DateTime is an IConvertible, and it implements ToDateTime very simply:

```
    DateTime IConvertible.ToDateTime(IFormatProvider provider)
    {
        return this;
    }
```

As Chris pointed out, there is no reason to convert DateTime.Now to a DateTime.  It already is one.

Comment: I have also tried just DateTime.Now.Date/Datetime.Now/Datetime.Today/Datetime.Now.ToString/Datetime.Now.Date.ToString as well all giving the same error